# Color shading edges Powerpoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, colors

I am drawing some geometric art in Powerpoint and it is working better than expected. I am trying to make a shape that consist of 30 hexagons in a 6x5 matrix. I want to color shade the fill from one side to another and I was capable of doing this by grouping all the individual hexagons. I now want to color shade the edges as well, but it shades them one by one. Is this possible in Powerpoint? Here is an example image without the shading applied.

[image]

Comment: You would be better off using a drawing tool for this and then importing the image into PowerPoint.

Comment: @DavidPostill Any suggestions on what drawing apps make you draw regular hexagons easily?

Comment: [gimp hexagon - Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=gimp+hexagon)

Comment: FWIW, while drawing this shouldn't be all that difficult, PPT will fight you tooth and nail about the edges. I've tried several different ways of automating this in VBA, but shortfalls in the object model or the outright freakish behavior of shapes like this stymied me. Ex: click to select your group, click to select just one of the hexagons, then look at its fill in the Format Shape dialog. Note that none of the fill type radio buttons is selected. And when you select one, the fill of the hexagon changes to something unwanted.